pulling docker image using pipeline in aks hosted build agent pod
jobs:
- job: RunTests
displayName: Run Tests
pool:
name: aks_hosted_agent_pod
container:
image: 'python:3.11'
steps:
--> other stages of the pipeline.
The error is:
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/__a/externals/node/bin/node": stat /__a/externals/node/bin/node: no such file or directory: unknown
In the pipeline logs i can see that it's able to pull the image but not able to run it, I even have node installed.
This only happens when I point it to the aks hosted pod build agent, and if I direct it to the build agent which is hosted in linux or azure hosted linux agent pool no issues and it works perfectly pulling the image and running it even if I don't have the nodej installed.
But for my tasks I have to make this run in the aks hosted build agent pool.
Any suggestions please.

For the Docker agent hosted on AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service), Docker-in-Docker is unavailable. For more details, see "Run an agent in Docker".



Yes, my present build agent docker follows the same reference from the azure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#use-azure-kubernetes-service-cluster

@ManojND, Yes, this is the official documentation of Azure DevOps. As stated in the documentation, Docker-in-Docker is not available for the Docker agents hosted on AKS. However, if you use the docker image to set up an Azure VM or VMSS, Docker-in-Docker is available for the agents hosted on the VM/VMSS. If you prefer, maybe, you can consider configuring the Docker agent on Azure VM/VMSS.

I tried using the azure vm, and it works totally fine, but my present task is to not use the azure vm that's why I build this self hosted build agent. turns out it's not working out.

@ManojND, Okay, I can understand your demands. However, it is unfortunate that Docker-in-Docker is not available for the Docker agents hosted on AKS. This is the restriction from AKS and seem no method to ignore it.

I will  try some other approach thanks for letting me know @Bright Ran-MSFT

@ManojND, No problem. Please go ahead.
